# How do I add an edit option for the values of stored objects in a dropdown menu using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, object

Brief background: Before the user enters any information the select menu is hidden, once he clicks the "Add a track" button the object is stored as an option. I need to add an "edit" option so that the user can select any of the stored objects and be able to change any of the values. Did I corner myself by making the display a dropdown? What would be the smartest approach to implement an edit option? It doesn't have to be a dropdown menu, I'm open to other display options if it makes it easier.

```js
var tracks = [];

/*Song selection becomes visible only if there is at least one song added*/
function myLoad() {
  let htmlSelect = document.getElementById("songList");
  htmlSelect.style.visibility = "hidden";

  if (sessionStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("songs", JSON.stringify(tracks));
    sessionStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
  } else {
    tracks = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("songs"));
    let i = 0;
    tracks.forEach(function(s) {
      let optItem = document.createElement("option");
      optItem.innerHTML = s.songTitle;
      optItem.value = i;
      i = i + 1;
      htmlSelect.appendChild(optItem);
    });
    if (i > 0) {
      htmlSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }
}

//Constructor for songs
function Song(songTitle, artist, album, genre) {
  this.songTitle = songTitle;
  this.artist = artist;
  this.album = album;
  this.genre = genre;
}

/*Songs are added through the function below*/
function addSong() {
  tracks = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("songs"));
  let newSong = new Song(
    document.getElementById("titleSong").value,
    document.getElementById("artistName").value,
    document.getElementById("albumName").value,
    document.getElementById("genreName").value,
  );
  tracks.push(newSong);
  sessionStorage.setItem("songs", JSON.stringify(tracks));
}

/* When the user chooses a different Song from the select (dropdown) element on the HTML page,
the function below will be called.*/
function ChangeActiveSong(indexOfTrackSong) {
  tracks[indexOfTrackSong].track = function() {
    alert(
      this.songTitle +
      " by " +
      this.artist +
      " from the album " +
      this.album +
      " of the " +
      this.genre +
      " genre."
    );
  };
  tracks[indexOfTrackSong].track();
}
```

```html
<body onload="myLoad()">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="titleSong">Song Title: </label>
      <input type="text" name="titleSong" id="titleSong" required>
      <label for="artistName">Artist: </label>
      <input type="text" name="artistName" id="artistName" required>
      <label for="albumName">Album: </label>
      <input type="text" name="albumName" id="albumName">
      <label for="genre">Music Genre: </label>
      <input type="text" name="genreName" id="genreName">
      <button onclick="addSong()">Add a track</button>
  </div>
  </form>
  <select id="songList" onchange="ChangeActiveSong(this.value)">
    <option value="">--Please choose a song--</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: I formatted your code and moved the /div to make the HTML valid. Why is the select not inside the form? I wanted to make you a snippet but they do not work with sessionStorage

Comment: You want them to be able to edit values in the dropdown, or add their own? You might be able to use a [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)?

Comment: @mplungjan the select only becomes visible when an object(song with its details) has been added. I don't mind changing the dropdown menu for a table, a list, etc. if it's better to enable an option to edit each object.

Comment: @GammaGames I want the user to be able to activate an option to edit any of the values that make up the object (album name, genre, song title, artist), which were entered previously and have been added. I feel like a datalist would have the same structure limitations as select in regards to enabling the mentioned option.

Comment: @MorMql You could use a dropdown, then when the user selects a value add an "Edit" button that will let you edit the currently selected value. Just update the selected value after editing, if the value text was changed. Depending on the number of options, maybe a radio list or something would be better?